# How to add a condition in sort order?

Tags: magento-enterprise, products, sorting, promotions, product-collection

Please help me i have a problem with the product sorting condition
i.e
Actual Requirement : need to show promotional products at first.and then order by quantity..

If product is promotional then i have to show the oldest promotion to date at first..

this promotion to date sort will apply when the product is promotion only..
like if(product is promotion) order by promotion_to_date asc

Please help me...
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Check this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14669/146. It won't solve your problem but it will give you an idea on how you can manipulate the sorting based on some custom attributes and conditions.

Comment: actually i have tried with this code 
$mainproductcollection->getSelect() ->joinLeft('catalog_product_entity_int AS feat', 'feat.entity_id=e.entity_id and feat.attribute_id=1004 and feat.entity_type_id=4')
  ->order('feat.value ' . 'desc');
$mainproductcollection->addAttributeToSort('promotion_to_date', 'asc');
$mainproductcollection->getSelect() ->joinLeft('cataloginventory_stock_item AS so', 'so.product_id=e.entity_id')  ->group('e.entity_id')->order('qty ' . 'desc');

Comment: Forexample:
product_id | featured | promotion_to_date | qty
1       1        2014-07-30       9
2       0        null              16
3       1        2014-08-30      10
4       1        2014-08-30      15
5       0        null              10
6       0        2014-05-30      18

Comment: it shows like after apply all conditions
product_id | featured | promotion_to_date | qty
1       1        2014-07-30       9
4       1        2014-08-30      15
3       1        2014-08-30      10
2       0        null              16
5       0        null              10
6       0        2014-05-30      18

Comment: but we need to display
product_id | featured | promotion_to_date | qty
1       1        2014-07-30       9
4       1        2014-08-30      15
3       1        2014-08-30      10
6       0        2014-05-30      18
2       0        null              16
5       0        null              10
why because 6th product is not featured (means previously it's featured that date was expired so that featured value changed to 0(No))
Thanks for your reply,please help me