# Is there a way to change the position of a product for all attributes it belongs to?

Tags: catalog, sorting, position, sort

So if you sort with `best value` it uses the products `position` attribute in the category to decide the position.

The lower the higher it appears on the catalog page and search page.

We have a custom `sold-out` attribute that on some products is `yes`.

On those products we would like the position to be `9999` for all categories it belongs to.

Is there a way to change it on a per product level or do you have to change it on each category?

If there is a programmatic way that would also be the next best prize.

Comment: You can take a look at this [question and answer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/14664/146). It's kind of similar. When sorting by position, actually sort by some other attribute first and then by position. Maybe you can adapt it to fit your needs.

Comment: Which Magento version are you using ?

Comment: I am using Magento 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is assuming you're using Magento 1, let me know if you're on Magento 2

The positions are stored directly in the `catalog_category_product` table.

My suggestions would be to get the list of product ids that need to be updated with a code like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
         ->addAttributeToFilter('sold-out','yes');

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    echo $product->getProductId() . ",";
}
```

Once you got that list you can run a SQL query directly on your database that will look like this:

```
UPDATE catalog_category_product SET position = 9999 WHERE product_id IN (1,2,3)
```

1, 2 and 3 are for the example, just replace them with the list of product id you got from the code I pasted and separate them with commas.